# convert opencv vector Point2f to vector Point

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, point

I want to convert the centers obtained by contouring of type `vector<Point2f>centers(contours.size());` to integer points so that I can plot the centers.
If I print out the centers then they are all in floating point, so how to convert this vector floating points to integer floating points?

```
cout << "Center:" << centers[i] << endl;
Output : Center:[474.273, 273.845]
```

I want to round up the values so that I can use this points to plot coordinates on the image.

Comment: all point types can be converted to other point types.
i.e. `my_integer_point = static_cast<integer_point>(my_float_point);`

Comment: can you give an example of it as what is ```integer point```

Comment: Got it ```newcenters[i] = static_cast<Point>(centers[i]);```